# Solving a system of 4 equations and 4 unknowns.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following system of equations: $x = \beta x$, $y = \beta y$, $z = -\beta/2$, and $x^2 + y^2 - z + h = 0$. We are trying to solve for $x,y,z,\beta$.

My attempt at solving this problem is to start with the first equation and note that $x(1-\beta) = 0$. Therefore, $\beta = 1$.

But apparently this is incorrect! Why? It satisfies the first equation!

Comment: $x$ can be zero too. In such cases, $\beta$ can be any value.

Comment: So wait a second. How do we know if it is $x=0$ or $\beta = 1$?

Answer (score 1):

If $\beta \neq 1$, then $x = y = 0$ from the first two equations.

From the last equation, $z = h$ and finally from the third equation, $\beta = -2h$